# Does this complex function have removable singularity at the indicated point.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, singularity

I am trying to classify the singularity of $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{(z-\pi)^2}$ at $z=\pi$. I need to know whether this function converges to a point when $z\to \pi$. But I am unable to figure out whether it has a removable singularity, a pole or essential singularity at $z=\pi$.I was thinking of making a power series of $\sin z$ at $z=\pi$. Can someone help me with this problem?

**My attempt**

$\sin z=-(z-\pi)+\frac{1}{3!}(z-\pi)^3-\frac{1}{5!}(z-\pi)^5+....$

so that $\frac{\sin z}{(z-\pi)^2}=\frac{-1}{z-\pi}+G(z)$ where $G(z)$ is analytic. So, $f(z)$ has a pole of order $1$ i.e. a simple pole at $z=\pi$.

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number $z_0$ is a pole of order $k$ of the function $f(z),$ which is analytic in $0<|z-z_0|<r$ if an only if  the following limit exists and is not equal $0.$
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)^k f(z)\neq 0$$
The function $f(z)=\displaystyle {\sin z\over (z-\pi)^2}$ satisfies
$$\lim_{z\to \pi} (z-\pi)f(z)=\lim_{z\to \pi} {\sin z\over z-\pi}=-\lim_{z\to \pi} {\sin (z-\pi)\over z-\pi}=-\lim_{u\to 0}{\sin u\over u}=-1$$

Comment: Can you give me a proof of the result you stated?

Comment: I have found nice lecture [notes](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.math.uci.edu/~ndonalds/math147/6residues.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi3pcPjupH4AhXi-SoKHTZGDrQQFnoECBoQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3fbZJiv_bLuy65Pu3ldwTl) See Theorem 6.7

Comment: But it is not the statement you wrote.

Comment: I believe it is the same statement, I mean the first sentence. Observe that  $$\lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)^mf(z)=\varphi(z_0)\neq 0$$ See also a short proof there at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I haven't mentioned in my answer that $\varphi(z)$ is analytic also at $z=z_0,$ but this you get for free. If you like a can add a proof, if the one from the notes is not satisfying for you.